# onValueChange keeps flooding my socket server

Tags: javascript, sockets, react-native, socket.io

I have a react native application with a slider that goes from 0 to 100%. Everytime the user touch this slider `onValueChange` is triggered, sending the changed value to the a server via a socket.

This is the code

```
       <Slider  
             step={1}
             minimumValue={0}
             maximumValue={100}
             value={this.state.value}
             onValueChange={val => {
               this.setState({ whiteValue: val })
               socket.emit('channel', val)
              }
            }
       />
```

The problem is that everytime the user touch the slider (even if he does not modify the value), `onValueChange` is triggered like every 0.3 seconds.

Because I want the changed value to be sent to my server via the socket, the server is flooded by values and can't handle them fast enough.

What is the best way to "reduce" the emitting rate ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need [Debouncing](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/).

Comment: Throttle solved my problem !

Comment: I thought debouncing was better for the case, with `{leading:false;trailing:true}` as it will only fire once, at the end. Throttle is a way to fire it multiple times but no sooner than `waitTime`. But I guess you know better what's best for your case :). Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however I'm coding an app that is modifiying a ledstrip color, so as I swipe on the slider I want to see the color live changing. Again, thanks for the precious help !

Answer (score 1):

You may want to refer to https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2454, debouncing is exactly what you need, but you may need to implement it yourself. I would most likely do something like this:

```html
       <Slider  
             step={1}
             minimumValue={0}
             maximumValue={100}
             value={this.state.value}
             onValueChange={val => {
               if (this.oldVal === val) return;
               else {
                   this.oldVal = val;
                   this.setState({ whiteValue: val })
                   socket.emit('channel', val)
               }               
              }
            }
       />
```